# System error 5 on net use drive mapping when including password, no error when prompting for password

Tags: windows, network-share

I get a 'System error 5 has occurred. Access is Denied' error when I do:
`net use t: \\server\transfer /user:bpm_r bpm_rxt`

However, I get a successful map if I do:
`net use t: \\server\transfer /user:bpm_r`
... followed by a prompt for a password 'bpm_rxt' and type it in manually

Comment: Does your password contain any characters that need to be escaped?

Answer (score 3):

Formatting the user id as: DOMAIN\user seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: what does that mean?